where does the condition of aggregate demand can be written as function of aggregate wealth come from
I'm self studying MWG chapter 4, and it says the aggregate demand $x(p,w_1,...,w_I)=\Sigma_{i=1}^Ix_i(p,w_i)$ can be written as function of $W=\Sigma_i^I w_i$, that is $\Sigma_{i=1}^Ix_i(p,w_i)=x(p,W)$, we must have $$\Sigma_i\frac{\partial x_{li}(p,w_i)}{\partial w_i} dw_i=0$$ under $\Sigma dw_i=0$.
I want to know why this is the case mathematically, where does it come from. Can anyone prove it?

Consider a change in the distribution of wealth $dw_i$ that leaves aggregate wealth $\sum_i w_i = W$ unchanged:
$$
\sum_i dw_i = 0,
$$
Let $X(p, w_1, \ldots, w_N)$ be aggregate demand. Now assume this can be written in terms of prices and aggregate wealth $W$. Then we get:
$
X(p,\underbrace{W}_{\sum_i w_i})$.
As such,
$$
\sum_i x_i(p, w_i) = X(p,W).
$$
Taking the differential gives:
$$
\sum_i \frac{\partial x_i(p,w_i)}{\partial w_i} dw_i = \frac{\partial X(p,W)}{\partial W} \sum_i \underbrace{\frac{\partial W}{\partial w_i}}_{=1} dw_i. = 0
$$

This is false. Consider the degenerate distribution dwᵢ = δ(wᵢ) (that is, all wealth held by one person). The aggregate demand goes to something that looks like C₀ + log(wᵢ).

In this case, $W = w_i$, so $dW = dw_i = 0$.

$x(p,\sum_{i=1}^{I}w_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i})$ hold in all generality if for any two distribution of same wealth $(w_{1},...,w_{I})$ and $(w_{1}',...,w_{I}')$,
$\sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i}')$, s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{I}dw_{i} = 0$ is true
Now,
Consider two distribution of same wealth $(w_{1},...,w_{I})$ and $(w_{1}+dw_{1},...,w_{I}+dw_{I})$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{I}dw_{i} = 0$ then we must have,
$\sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i}+dw_{i})$
$\sum_{i=1}^{I}x_{i}(p,w_{i}) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{I} \left( x_{i}(p,w_{i}) + \dfrac{\partial x_{i}(p,w_{i})}{\partial w_{i}}.dw_{i} \right) $
which gives us:
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{I} \left( \dfrac{\partial x_{i}(p,w_{i})}{\partial w_{i}}.dw_{i} \right) = 0$

There is not reference to the aggregate demand $x(p,\sum_{i=1}^I w_i)$ in your calculus.

for that to hold the aggregate demand must be same for any two distribution of the same total wealth. So i have started from there.
